# UIToolBar position on iPhone X Simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios11, iphone-x

test project with TabBarController containing view controller embedded in navigation controller. dropped bar button items and activated the bar.

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

The safe area layout guide is checked. This doesn't happen on other simulator. did someone encounter this as well? Is there any fix or workaround?

[image: hovering uitoolbar iPhone x]
[image: test project]
[image: iphone se Sim]

Comment: this bug is stil there after installing Xcode 9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by Apple. verified with Xcode 9.2 (simulator and iOS 11.2.2 iPhone X).